# Do-while loop only executing when it feels like it in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, while-loop, do-while

So I have this do-while loop which is supposed to repeat asking if you want to enter info for a student if you do press y and enter info via an input() function the data is then stored in a vector. If you press q, the program is supposed to print the info contained in the vector and exit the loop.

For some reason the loop fully executes for the first and second student you enter. Then instead of repeating the loop asking if you want to enter a third student it seems to just execute the input() function. It doesn't ask you 'Enter y to continue or q to quit' and any student info you enter here does not seemed to be stored. It does this intermittently changing between executing the full loop and just the input() function. I'm wondering if anyone knows why this is happening and what I can do to fix it.

Cheers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int NO_OF_TEST = 4;

struct studentType
{
    string studentID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string subjectName;
    string courseGrade;

    int arrayMarks[4];

    double avgMarks;
};

studentType input();
double calculate_avg(int marks[],int NO_OF_TEST); // returns the average mark
string calculate_grade (double avgMark); // returns the grade 

void main()
{
    unsigned int n=0; // no. of student
    vector<studentType> vec; // vector to store student info
    studentType s;

    char response;
    do
    {
        cout << "\nEnter y to continue or q to quit... ";
        cin >> response;
        if (response == 'y')
        {
            n++;
            for(size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
            {
                s = input();
                vec.push_back(s);
            }
        }

        else if (response == 'q')
        {
            for (unsigned int y=0; y<n; y++)
            {
                cout << "\nFirst name: " << vec[y].firstName;
                cout << "\nLast name: " << vec[y].lastName;
                cout << "\nStudent ID: " << vec[y].studentID;
                cout << "\nSubject name: " << vec[y].subjectName;
                cout << "\nAverage mark: " << vec[y].avgMarks;
                cout << "\nCourse grade: " << vec[y].courseGrade << endl << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    while(response!='q');
}

studentType input()
{   
    studentType newStudent;

    cout << "\nPlease enter student information:\n";

    cout << "\nFirst Name: ";
    cin >> newStudent.firstName;

    cout << "\nLast Name: ";
    cin >> newStudent.lastName;

    cout << "\nStudent ID: ";
    cin >> newStudent.studentID;

    cout << "\nSubject Name: ";
    cin >> newStudent.subjectName;

    for (int x=0; x<NO_OF_TEST; x++)
    {   cout << "\nTest " << x+1 << " mark: ";
        cin >> newStudent.arrayMarks[x];
    }

    newStudent.avgMarks = calculate_avg(newStudent.arrayMarks,NO_OF_TEST );
    newStudent.courseGrade = calculate_grade (newStudent.avgMarks);

    return newStudent;
}

double calculate_avg(int marks[], int NO_OF_TEST)
{
     double sum=0;

     for( int i=0; i<NO_OF_TEST; i++)
     {
         sum = sum+ marks[i];
     }

     return sum/NO_OF_TEST;

}


string calculate_grade (double avgMark)
{
    string grade= "";

    if (avgMark<50)
    {
        grade = "Fail";
    }

    else if (avgMark<65)
    {
        grade = "Pass";
    }

    else if (avgMark<75)
    {
        grade = "Credit";
    }       

    else if (avgMark<85)
    {
        grade = "Distinction";
    }

    else
    {
        grade = "High Distinction";
    }

    return grade;
}
```

Comment: `void main` isn't legal C++. Use `int`. And take a close look at what happens if you enter `y` when `n` becomes 2 or more.

Comment: `newStudent` object doesn't have a member named `arrayMarks`. Post your actual code.

Comment: Your source code does not compile.

Comment: Why are you looping for the `input` call? It means that the first time you call `input` once, the second time though the `do ... while` loop you call `input` twice, the third time you call `input` thrice, etc.

Comment: When the `response == 'y'`, why do you enter into `for` loop? What is the purpose of that `for` loop?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af7e1f982efdcaa9 just to get you started

Comment: @user2850913, I think it's a good time for your teacher to learn it then. `void main` wasn't allowed in the first standard and still isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code does it:

```
        n++;
        for(size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            s = input();
            vec.push_back(s);
        }
```

It asks you for two students the second time, for three student the third time, etc.

So, make it

```
        vec.push_back(input());
```